# How to find position of search keyword in full text search?

Tags: c#, full-text-search, sql-server-express

I am using Sql Express Advanced with Full Text Search in my C# project. I am using this Sql statement to find documents.

```
select id,Name,TypeID,StatusID from document where Contains([Content],'FormsOf (INFLECTIONAL, \"" + TextBoxSearch.Text + "\")')
```

It is working fine. What I want is to find the position of the search keyword in a text.
Is there any built function or any 3rd party code to do this.

I could do it with stemming classes but it is too complicated and can not find when there are more two words.